# Live-Action Dystopian Cyberpunk(?) Sci-fi movie/show

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, cyberpunk

There's really only one scene I remember clearly, but I have no idea where or when I watched it. It might have been several years ago.

Many people seem to have bionic parts of some kind. One woman is interrogating another woman sitting across from her. Suddenly, the interrogator's boot/shoe turns into a terrifying, large black spike. She lifts her leg and impales the other women in the stomach with it.

I think that there was also a chase of some kind.

That's unfortunately all I remember, but the scene with the impaling must have been shocking enough for me to remember it after all this time.

Comment: Was this a piece of animation or live action?

Comment: It was live action.

Comment: When her foot turned into a spike, was it a physical effect or something with CGI morphing?

Comment: It was some kind of CGI. It literally morphed from a normal-looking boot to a massive, sharp, black thing. I seem to recall that the woman with the spike foot had long hair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Killjoys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killjoys) Season 3, Episode 2, A Skinner, Darkly**

One of the two concurrent plots in the episode involves Johnny interacting with a group of "hackmods", the show's term for cybernetically enhanced characters. The character with the spiked leg is Niko - you can see about three seconds of her at the very end of [this Youtube trailer for the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zplDAOd_VgQ).  See [here](https://killjoys.fandom.com/wiki/A_Skinner,_Darkly) for a summary of the episode plot.

At 9:46 in the episode, Niko is speaking to a woman who had an allergic reaction to the stolen human skin she was wearing (don't ask).  Niko unzips the thigh-high leather boot she is wearing on her left leg, revealing the artificial, black, spiked leg which she then extends to impale the woman through the chest (not the stomach), with the spike protruding out through the back of the chair the woman was sitting in.  There is no chase at that point, though there are various action scenes through the episode.

Season 3 of Killjoys first screened in mid-2017, so that matches the "several years ago" timeframe.

Comment: This is it. Now that I've seen the scene, I know for sure that this is it. It's interesting that I remembered it...it must have been pretty shocking to me at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the live action [*Fullmetal Alchemist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_(film)) movie?

> Live-Action Dystopian Cyberpunk(?) Sci-fi movie/show

It is set in an alternative present where alchemy is a well developed science, so there are both familiar technologies like trains and people with magic-like powers.

> It might have been several years ago.

It was released at the end of 2017, which may or may not match your definition.

> Many people seem to have bionic parts of some kind.

The main character, Edward Elric, has a mechanical arm and leg (this kind of prostheses are named "automail" and are a well-known technology in that world, so other people could have some too), while his brother Alphonse is an empty suit of armor (it's complicated ...).

> One woman is interrogating another woman sitting across from her. Suddenly, the interrogator's boot/shoe turns into a terrifying, large black spike. She lifts her leg and impales the other women in the stomach with it.

This might not match perfectly, but is similar to what you remember.
One of the villains is an homunculus named Lust having the appearance of a beatiful woman; her fingers can turn into long sharp black claws.
I haven't watched the movie, and it has been a long time since I watched the animated series, so I don't know whether she can turn her feet into weapons too.
The movie poster shows her in the top center position, together with many other characters.

[image: Fullmetal alchemist movie poster]

The [IMDB Fullmetal Alchemist image gallery](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5607028/mediaindex?ref_=tt_mv_close) contains *a lot* of stills, so you can check if this is the movie you were looking for.